# When particular text is entered, make the button clickable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to make a button clickable when a particular text is entered.
Example: When 'allow me' is entered, the button 'get in here' should be enable to be clicked. JS or jQuery is fine.

EDIT:

Here's some code:

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/main.php';


/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle visits with a login token. If it is
    valid, log the person in.
---------------------------------------------------*/


if(isset($_GET['tkn'])){

    // Is this a valid login token?
    $user = User::findByToken($_GET['tkn']);

    if($user){

        // Yes! Login the user and redirect to the protected page.

        $user->login();
        redirect('protected.php');
    }

    // Invalid token. Redirect back to the login form.
    redirect('index.php');
}



/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle logging out of the system. The logout
    link in protected.php leads here.
---------------------------------------------------*/


if(isset($_GET['logout'])){

    $user = new User();

    if($user->loggedIn()){
        $user->logout();
    }

    redirect('index.php');
}


/*--------------------------------------------------
    Don't show the login page to already 
    logged-in users.
---------------------------------------------------*/


$user = new User();

if($user->loggedIn()){
    redirect('protected.php');
}



/*--------------------------------------------------
    Handle submitting the login form via AJAX
---------------------------------------------------*/


try{

    if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){

        // Output a JSON header

        header('Content-type: application/json');

        // Is the email address valid?

        if(!isset($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            throw new Exception('Please enter a valid email.');
        }

        // This will throw an exception if the person is above 
        // the allowed login attempt limits (see functions.php for more):
        rate_limit($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        // Record this login attempt
        rate_limit_tick($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['email']);

        // Send the message to the user

        $message = '';
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = 'Your Login Link';

        if(!User::exists($email)){
            $subject = "Thank You For Registering!";
            $message = "Thank you for registering at our site!\n\n";
        }

        // Attempt to login or register the person
        $user = User::loginOrRegister($_POST['email']);


        $message.= "You can login from this URL:\n";
        $message.= get_page_url()."?tkn=".$user->generateToken()."\n\n";

        $message.= "The link is going expire automatically after 10 minutes.";

        $result = send_email($fromEmail, $_POST['email'], $subject, $message);

        if(!$result){
            throw new Exception("There was an error sending your email. Please try again.");
        }

        die(json_encode(array(
            'message' => 'Thank you! We\'ve sent a link to your inbox. Check your spam folder as well.'
        )));
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){

    die(json_encode(array(
        'error'=>1,
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    )));
}

/*--------------------------------------------------
    Output the login form
---------------------------------------------------*/

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title></title>

        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- The main CSS file -->
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="login-register" method="post" action="index.php">

            <h1>Login or Register</h1>

            <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" name="email" autofocus />
            <p>Enter your email address above and we will send <br />you a login link.</p>

            <button type="submit">Login / Register</button>

            <span></span>

        </form>

        <!-- JavaScript Includes -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I need the button with Login / Register to be enabled if a particular email is entered.

Comment: Where is `"allow me"` entered? What have you tried to solve Question?

Comment: in a textbox and i tried to look it up on google

Comment: this is not a free code writing service - what have you tried?

Comment: The question is too broad: *"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `<button>` element `disabled` attribute, `<button disabled>click</button>`.
Attach `input` event listener to element where text is entered by user using `.addEventListener`. Within `input` event handler check if user entered exact phrase using strict equality operator `text === text`, if condition is `true` remove `disabled` attribute from `<button>` element, else set `disabled` attribute at `<button>` element.

Comment: got so far: `document.addEventListener("input", function(){
});`

Comment: @MarshyM You can attach event to the element. Then use `if`, e.g., `if (this.value === "text") {button.removeAttribute("disabled")} else {
  button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
}`

Comment: huh? (sorry i just started js)

Comment: @MarshyM The `if` statement would be placed within the `input` event handler. `this` refers to the current element where `event` occurred; you could alternatively include `event` parameter at `function(event) {}` and use `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` to refer to the element where event occurred; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget. `.value` is the text value of `input` element. If value of `input` element is equal to string `"allow me"` remove `disabled` attribute from `button` element, else set `disabled` attribute at `button` element

Comment: @MarshyM Try html`<button type="submit" disabled>Login / Register</button>` javascript .`document.querySelector("input[type=email]").addEventListener("input", function(){if (this.value === "abc@123") {button.removeAttribute("disabled")} else { button.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled") } })` or `var button = $("button[type=submit]"); $("input[type=email]").on("input", function(event) {button.prop("disabled", !(this.value === "abc@123"))})`

Comment: both don't work: https://jsfiddle.net/33mne5sg/ and https://jsfiddle.net/sfxtc90q/

Comment: @MarshyM Mistakenly, here, suggested `[type=email]` where `[type=text]` is `type` at `input` element https://jsfiddle.net/33mne5sg/1, same here, also`button` was not defined https://jsfiddle.net/sfxtc90q/1

Comment: how do i set it equal to an array or multiple things?

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.some()`, `if (["abc@123", "def@456"].some(function(value) { value === input.value})) {}`

Comment: i don't understand can you add it to the fiddle please?